# How to add multiple records in Google Sheets using JavaScript and App Script

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project, in this project I am performing CRUD operations on Google Sheets using JavaScript and App Script, main CRUD is done and working perfect. Now i want to try something different in it, I want to import excel generated .xlsx file, import it in HTML table, and then upload that excel file content into Google Sheets, problem I'm facing right now is,  I saved all excel file content in a array, and using for loop I'm sending GET request through AJAX to App Script, Now lets say I have 10 records in  my excel file, problem is that sometimes it uploads only 2 records or only 3 record or sometimes it just replace other records which are uploaded while the loop was in progress. May be it is some kind of sync issue..

Retrieved data from Excel file:

```
var bulkData=[
       {
          "Company":"",
          "Contact":"",
          "Title":"Temp",
          "Department":"DEAD2013",
          "Phone":"",
          "Salutation":"",
          "Address_1":"",
          "Address_2":"",
          "Address_3":"",
          "Country":"United States",
          "Email":""
       },
       {
          "Company":"",
          "Contact":"[69] 34234234/3434-1212",
          "Title":"Sdasd Tay",
          "Department":"Consultant",
          "Phone":"[55] 3411866",
          "Salutation":"Mr. AWW Yweewe",
          "Address_1":"317, Heea Road,",
          "Address_2":"#232, Holiday Inn QWA",
          "Address_3":"(Cwew Med Centre),",
          "Zip":"6534545",
          "Country":"",
          "Email":"wewe@ss.com.sg"
       },
       {
          "Company":"AA & Qds Dev",
          "Contact":"[23]  2323 6656",
          "Title":"Inthira",
          "Department":"Architect",
          "Phone":"[46]  4323 2345 ",
          "Salutation":"Zee C B",
          "Address_1":"Qwe 158 sad fff Street 11",
          "Address_2":"",
          "Address_3":"",
          "Zip":"3433",
          "Country":"Singapore",
          "Email":"asd@asd.com.sg"
       },
    ]
```

Function use to save multiple rows in Google Sheet:

```
        function insertBulkData()
        {
            console.log(bulkData);
            var j=1;
            for (let i = 0; i < bulkData.length; i++) 
            {

                var url = script_url 
                + "?callback=ctrlq&id=" + (lastId+j)
                + "&address1=" + String(bulkData[i].Address_1).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&address2=" + String(bulkData[i].Address_2).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                
                + "&address3=" + String(bulkData[i].Address_3).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&city=" + String(bulkData[i].City).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&company=" + String(bulkData[i].Company).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                
                + "&contact=" + String(bulkData[i].Contact).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&country=" + String(bulkData[i].Country).replaceAll( "#", "" ) 
                + "&department=" + String(bulkData[i].Department).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                
                + "&email=" + String(bulkData[i].Email).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&fax=" + String(bulkData[i].Fax).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&phone=" + String(bulkData[i].Phone).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                
                + "&product=" + String(bulkData[i].Product).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&salutation=" + String(bulkData[i].Salutation).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&title=" + String(bulkData[i].Title).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                
                + "&website=" + String(bulkData[i].Web_Site).replaceAll( "#", "" )  
                + "&zip=" + String(bulkData[i].Zip).replaceAll( "#", "" )  +
                "&action=insert";


                $.ajax({
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: url,
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                });
                j++;
            }
        }
```

App script code to insert data in Google Sheets:

```
function insert_value(request, sheet) {
    var id = request.parameter.id;
    var address1 = request.parameter.address1;
    var address2 = request.parameter.address2;
    var address3 = request.parameter.address3;

    var city = request.parameter.city;
    var country = request.parameter.country;
    var company = request.parameter.company;
    var contact = request.parameter.contact;

    var fax = request.parameter.fax;
    var department = request.parameter.department;
    var email = request.parameter.email;
    var phone = request.parameter.phone;

    var product = request.parameter.product;
    var salutation = request.parameter.salutation;
    var title = request.parameter.title;
    var website = request.parameter.website;

    var zip = request.parameter.zip;

    var rowData = sheet.appendRow([id,company,contact,title,department,phone,fax,salutation,product,website,address1,address2,address3,city,zip,country,email]); 
    var result="Insertion successful";

    result = JSON.stringify({
        "result": result
    });  
    
    return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: I have some data in JSON, i want to upload it in google sheets using JavaScript, to upload all the records which are in JSON array, i am using for loop so every time a new record will be inserted, But when the loop is completed i noticed that the record is not inserted correctly. Lets suppose the array have 5 records, then some times it only insert 3 records or may be some time 2 records means it is totally random. May be it is some sync or await issue, i have tried "when" function too but it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't still understand about the detail of your current issue and your goal.

Comment: I'm thinking `ajax` should make a synchronous call so that you make sure the spreadsheet is completely updated before calling the Apps Script URL in the next iteration. To do this, add the parameter `async: false`. `$.ajax({ async: false, ...})`. Can you check whether that solves your issue? If that's the case, I'd post this as an answer.